# Multiple VPN connections at the same time

Tags: windows, vpn, gateway, sms

I am investigating how to set up an SMS gateway that forwards messages to different mobile network operators. Connections to the operators are typically made via VPN. My question is how to configure the connections on my gateway server? Is it possible to create multiple VPN connections at the same time to create a route of some kind for each mobile operators server? 
My server is running Windows Server 2008
Please see figure 1 in the following link for a diagram of a typical setup: http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=294

Answer (score 2):

I once had set up 3 different vpn connections from the same machine, the only matter to be considered is the subnet you are connecting to. They have to be different.
Sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Answer (score 2):

Most VPN setups will give you an IP address on their network, typically an RFC1918 private one. As Gonzalo says, so long as each provider gives you a different address and network, then, you can have as many VPN connections as you like.

Things can get a little trickier if each of the VPN providers pushes a deafult route to your system. Each of them will then try to route all of your traffic over their connection, which can cause all sorts of mess. If this happens, you'll need to do some manual work after establishing the connections, to remove the default routes and establish specific ones only for each provider's network.

If you're not sure how to do this, connect to all of your providers and run 'route print' in the command line, then add it to your original post.